# Proof of $\Phi^\alpha =\{x\in\mathbb R\mid f(x)\leq \alpha \}$ bounded imply $f$ lower semi continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. We suppose that for all $\alpha \in\mathbb R$, $\Phi^\alpha =\{x\in\mathbb R\mid f(x)\leq \alpha \}$ closed. Prove that $f$ is Lower semi continuous. I think that my proof is very complicated, and I was wondering if there is easier or not ?

---

**Proof** Let $(x_n)$ a sequence that converge to $x_0$. Suppose by contradiction that $\liminf_{n\to \infty }f(x_n)<f(x_0)$. Set $y_n=\inf_{k\geq n}x_k$ and $\ell=\liminf_{n\to \infty }f(x_n)$. Let $\alpha \in\mathbb R$ s.t. $$\ell<\alpha <f(x_0).$$
By definition of $y_n$, for all $n\in\mathbb N^*$ there is $k_n\geq n$ s.t. $$f(x_{k_n})\leq y_n+\frac{1}{n}\leq \ell+\frac{1}{n},$$
where the last inequality comes from the fact that $(y_n)$ is increasing. So, let $N$ s.t. $\frac{1}{n}\leq \alpha -\ell$ for all $n\geq N$. In particular, $$f(x_{k_n})\leq \alpha <f(x_0),$$
for all $n\geq N$, and thus $(x_{k_n})_{n\geq N}$ is a sequence of $\Phi^\alpha $ that doesn't converges in $\Phi^\alpha $. Contradiction.

---

I think my proof is quite complicate. Is there easier ?

Comment: How do you define “lower semi continuous”? Besides, the question from the title is not the same as the question from the body.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: In $\mathbb R$ there are not millions of way to define lower semi continuity... Here it look to be $\liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x)\geq f(x_0)$ or equivalently, for all $x_n\to x_0$, $\liminf_{n\to \infty }f(x_n)\geq f(x_0)$.

Comment: It is possible. But it could also be$$(\forall a\in\mathbb R)(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta\implies f(x)>f(a)-\varepsilon.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: This is equivalent to the previous definitions. But indeed, the OP could have mention which definition he used (even if it looks quite obvious that he use the sequentially definition).

Comment: The title sounds pretty bad. OP has to edit the title.

Answer (score 1):

A very little simplification could be to remark that $$y_n+\frac{1}{n}\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow } \ell<\alpha,$$
and thus, there is $N$ s.t. $$f(x_{k_n})\leq y_n+\frac{1}{n}<\alpha $$ for all $n\geq N$. So no need to use the fact that $(y_n)$ is increasing.   But except this point, I'm not sure there is an easier proof. Well, I don't think that it's a very complicate proof neither...